# Average from different columns in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, average

I have a datafile with 10 columns as given below

```
ifile.txt
2  4  4  2  1  2  2  4  2  1
3  3  1  5  3  3  4  5  3  3
4  3  3  2  2  1  2  3  4  2
5  3  1  3  1  2  4  5  6  8
```

I want to add 11th column which will show the average of each rows along 10 columns. i.e. AVE(2 4 4 2 1 2 2 4 2 1) and so on. Though my following script is working well, but I would like to make it more simpler and short. I appreciate, in advance, for any kind help or suggestions in this regard.

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){s+=$i;ss+=$i}m=s/NF;$(NF+1)=ss/NF;s=ss=0}1' ifile.txt
```

Comment: You can remove the m vairable and its assignment completely as you never use it.

Answer (score 4):

This should work

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)x+=$i;$(NF+1)=x/NF;x=0}1' file
```

For each field you add the value to `x` in the loop.

Next you set field 11 to the sum in `x`divided by the number of fields `NF`.

Reset `x` to zero for the next line.

`1` equates to true and performs the default action in awk which is to print the line.

Answer (score 2):

is this helping

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)s+=$i;print $0,s/NF;s=0}' ifile.txt
```

or

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)ss+=$i;$(NF+1)=ss/NF;ss=0}1' ifile.txt
```

Comment: Note also that `for () {action} print` can be just `for () action; print`, since the brackets are just necessary if you are performing more than one thing. However, they make things clearer anyway.