# AWK: replacing distinct values, with averages, for duplicate entries

Tags: bash, awk, replace, average

I have many data files where each column represents a unique sample and each row corresponds to a gene name. Here is a sample of one of my smaller files:

```
MAPK3 9.49707613464767 9.34083460789419 9.12918870414545 
TIE1 5.12900020712651 5.15008091018047 5.15008091018047 
CYP2C19 3.80757247946463 3.80757247946463 3.87721584865861 
CXCR5 6.40745840005515 6.40745840005515 6.40745840005515 
CXCR5 6.04763929379884 6.13038198258514 6.13038198258514 
DUSP1 12.0320377077951 12.7960658385305 12.625340661444 
MMP10 4.1933379022831 4.1933379022831 4.1933379022831 
RXRG 4.33755505408386 4.32903686336417 4.32903686336417 
RXRG 6.91141485189572 6.96893082690402 6.96893082690402
```

Notice in the first column, the gene names `CXCR5` and `RXRG` have been duplicated, but the values for each entry is different. The output file I need would look like this:

```
MAPK3 9.49707613464767 9.34083460789419 9.12918870414545 
TIE1 5.12900020712651 5.15008091018047 5.15008091018047 
CYP2C19 3.80757247946463 3.80757247946463 3.87721584865861 
CXCR5 6.22754884693 6.2689201913201 6.2689201913201
DUSP1 12.0320377077951 12.7960658385305 12.625340661444 
MMP10 4.1933379022831 4.1933379022831 4.1933379022831 
RXRG 5.6244849529898 5.6489838451341 5.6489838451341
```

Where the duplicate gene's values are averaged and replace the original entries per sample. Additionally, I want to leave the unique gene names and values untouched. To be clear, I do not want an average value for the whole row, rather per column, for each duplicate gene name in column 1. 
I've tried to utilize clever awk one-liners as described here, [calculate and print the average value of strings in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19357707/calculate-and-print-the-average-value-of-strings-in-a-column), and here, [Average from different columns in shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31557317/average-from-different-columns-in-shell-script?rq=1) . But I'm having trouble generalizing the command to account for my files which could have as many as 100 samples/columns. And they muddle my unique gene names unnecessarily.

My novice level coding skills will be the death of me! Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR == 1 { CONVFMT="%."length($2)-index($2,".")"f" }
$1 != key { prt() }
{
    key=$1
    for (i=2 ; i<=NF ; i++) {
        sum[i] += $i
    }
    cnt++
}
END { prt() }

function prt() {
    if (key != "") {
        printf "%s", key
        for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
            printf "%s%s", OFS, sum[i] / cnt
        }
        print ""
    }
    delete sum
    cnt = 0
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
MAPK3 9.49707613464767 9.34083460789419 9.12918870414545
TIE1 5.12900020712651 5.15008091018047 5.15008091018047
CYP2C19 3.80757247946463 3.80757247946463 3.87721584865861
CXCR5 6.22754884692699 6.26892019132015 6.26892019132015
DUSP1 12.03203770779510 12.79606583853050 12.62534066144400
MMP10 4.19333790228310 4.19333790228310 4.19333790228310
RXRG 5.62448495298979 5.64898384513410 5.64898384513410
```

Comment: I found this to be exactly what I was looking for. Could you explain the code some?

Comment: The first line figures out the precision you are using based on the first value in the file so that will then be used for every other calculation. The 2nd line calls prt() when the key value changes to print the values associated with the preceding key. The next block (executed every time the current key is the same as the previous one) sums the values for each field and keeps a count of how many lines with that key were read. The END section calls prt() to print the values for the last key read. The prt() function prints the values.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!  Uses decorate/sort/undecorate pattern to keep the order of the rows the same.

```
$ awk '{f2[$1]+=$2; f3[$1]+=$3; f4[$1]+=$4; c[$1]++; r[$1]=NR}
    END{for(k in c) print r[k] "\t" k, f2[k]/c[k], f3[k]/c[k], f4[k]/c[k]}' file | 
sort -n | cut -f2

MAPK3 9.49708 9.34083 9.12919
TIE1 5.129 5.15008 5.15008
CYP2C19 3.80757 3.80757 3.87722
CXCR5 6.22755 6.26892 6.26892
DUSP1 12.032 12.7961 12.6253
MMP10 4.19334 4.19334 4.19334
RXRG 5.62448 5.64898 5.64898
```

to specify number of decimal points you can switch to `printf` with format modifiers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm very new to `awk` but this may do the trick (seems to work for me)

```
#!/bin/awk -f

{
    for(i = 2; i <= 4; ++i)
        id[$1][i] = (id[$1][i] * num[$1] + $i) / (num[$1] + 1);
    ++num[$1]
}

END {
    for(key in num)
        printf "%s %.15g %.15g %.15g \n", key, id[key][2], id[key][3], id[key][4]
}
```

**Output:**

```
$ cat test.txt|test.awk 
MMP10 4.1933379022831 4.1933379022831 4.1933379022831 
DUSP1 12.0320377077951 12.7960658385305 12.625340661444 
CYP2C19 3.80757247946463 3.80757247946463 3.87721584865861 
TIE1 5.12900020712651 5.15008091018047 5.15008091018047 
CXCR5 6.22754884692699 6.26892019132015 6.26892019132015 
RXRG 5.62448495298979 5.6489838451341 5.6489838451341 
MAPK3 9.49707613464767 9.34083460789419 9.12918870414545
```

It makes an associative array keyed on the first column name and keeps the running averages.